# Twilio Dialogflow cx one-click-integration fails with unspecified error, worked before

Tags: twilio, dialogflow-cx

@edit Through the browser developer console I was able to extract an actual error message:

> Invalid AvailableAddOnSid provided

But what does that actually mean. I find nothing on the web and in fact have no Twillio Add-Ons installed.

Yesterday I successfully integrated Dialogflow and Twilio per one-click-integration.

Today I wanted to do the same with another agent but always got an unspecified error when completing the last step in twilio. See screenshot of error in popup of last step in integration:

[image: Twilio Dialogflow cx integration setup error]

I did not change anything. What can it be and why isn't the error more specified?

Comment: Do these [link1](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/virtual-agent/dialogflow-cx-onboarding#configuration-steps-within-the-google-cloud-console),[link2](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/concept/integration/twilio) and [link3](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/quotas) help you?

Comment: No! I think it has something to do with Twillio. As I said it worked before.

Comment: It appears that this issue has to be investigated further, so if you have a support plan please create a new GCP [support case](https://cloud.google.com/support/). Otherwise, you can open a new issue on the [issue tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) describing your issue.

Comment: It seems that problem has already been solved by Twillio. I opened a ticket and they responded that it was an Twillio issue and should be solved now. I am testing it right now!